# SQL Server Network Service as dbo

Tags: sql-server, networking, service

I have SQL Server 2005 running on Windows Server 2003. I noticed that when I query the server from my web app (IIS 6.0 running app pool with Network Service) with a command containing `"SELECT USER_NAME()"`, I get "dbo" instead of `"NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE"`. I don't even have the NETWORK SERVICE running as dbo on my database.

How do I prevent NETWORK SERVICE running as dbo on my database?

As a side note, I ran the same code and database on my PC with Windows 7 (IIS 7), SQL Server 2008, and it returned the `"SELECT USER_NAME()"` as "NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE" which is exactly what I expect. What gives?

Edit:Sorry I didn't make changes to this post instead. I'm new at this. As I was saying, the original login was indeed network service and it's accessing the database as dbo which I didn't expect. The network service account didn't have sysadmin role or db_owner for the database. However, I looked up it's effective permissions and it's similar to that of a sysadmin. I made sure that network service isn't part of the local administrator group and it's not running the SQL server service itself. 
Looking up google for answers, I did come across someone with similar situation and they ended up querying the sys.login_token when running as the app to see what principal role it's giving the network service permission.
Anyway, it's late Friday and I'm gonna have to continue Monday. Cheers!

Comment: Have you verified which login account is actually running on the 2003 server using suser_sname() ?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to verify the **actual** login name then use [system_user](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms179930.aspx) or [suser_sname()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174427.aspx)

From books online regarding [user_name()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188014.aspx):

*If a Windows principal accesses the database by way of membership in a group, USER_NAME returns the name of the Windows principal instead of the group.*

Regarding the second part of your question, keeping it from running as dbo...

Read up on the [definition of dbo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa905208%28v=sql.80%29.aspx) here, but in short anything that is a sysadmin on your instance is going to be a dbo.

Answer (score 0):

It returns "dbo" on most of the servers I tried.

On one server it returned "guest".

Check this out.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188014.aspx